# Mocked Jest resolved value not being called but the actual function implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm working with ts-jest and I have the following in handler.ts and I'm having trouble mocking the getToken function that's being called inside fetchData, since I only want to test fetchData, I want to mock the response from getToken so it wouldn't make the axios request, but somehow when I run the test I see the "called getToken" console.

I know that moving getToken to a different file would work but I want to understand why is this case not working since I might come across this scenario multiple times

```
export const getToken = async (params: {}): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    console.log("called getToken");
    const oauthResponse = await axios.post(`url`, params);
    return oauthResponse.data.token;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Exception caught getting token");
  }
};

export const fetchData = async (params: {}): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    console.log("called fetchData");
    const tokenValue = await getToken(params);
    const response = await axios.post(`url`, params, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + tokenValue,
      },
    });
    return response.data.body;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Exception caught");
  }
};
```

And this is my handler.test.ts

```
import { fetchData, getToken } from "./handler";

...

  (getToken as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(mockedTokenValue);
  (axios.post as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(response);

  const result = await fetchData(params);

...
```

I've also tried

```
jest.mock(".handler", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("./handler"),
  getSFEToken: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return "mocked_token";
  })
}));
```

This is my jest.config.ts and my tsconfig.json for reference

```
import type { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};

export default config;
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "listFiles": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "es2015",
      "es2015.promise",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [".vscode", ".serverless", ".git", "node_modules/**/*", "dist"],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  },
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "*": ["src/*"]
  }
}
```

Ps. also reviewed this https://jestjs.io/docs/bypassing-module-mocks

Tried multiple mocking approaches and spies but the actual getToken implementation is being called rather than the mocked value

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test something is to **inject** its external dependencies.
You can mock module globally, but if your test function and the mocked one are in the same module (file) - they are both mocked.

For axios you need to do call import and call `jest.mock('axios')` for sure in the test file

In your case, you can have fetchData to accept getTockenFucntion optionally.

Example

```js
export const getToken = async (params: {}): Promise<string> {
  //....
}

export const fetchData = async (params: {}, getTockenFucntion = getToken): Promise<any> {
  //real implementation
}
```

```js
// the test file
import { fetchData } from "./handler";
import axios from "axios"

// mock axios globally
jest.mock('axios');

//we need this to manipulate the resosne on each test
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

describe("Some description", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // this is important to do 
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("Some test description", async () => {
    //setup
    const mokedResposne = {};
    mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue(mokedResposne);
    const getTockeMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue("whatever we want");

    //act
    await fetchData({}, getTockeMock);

    expect(getTockeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mokedResposne);
  });
})
```